# Errors in library fee code using multiple methods

Tags: c#

I'm making a library program that asks for users to input the amount of books checked out and the amount of days they are over due. If its under or equal to 7 days they are charge 10 cents for each book over due after 7 days its 20 cents for each book. We are supposed to use more than one method and I get two errors:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'totalCharge'
>
> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'daysOverdue' of Program.charge(double,double,double)'

I think I know what the first error means but I thought I already declared it a variable in the first line.

Here's the code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args){
        double totalCharge;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of books checked out.");
        double booksChecked = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of days they are 
         overdue.");
        double daysOverdue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Your total charge for {0} days overdue is {1}.", 
        daysOverdue, totalCharge.ToString("C"));
        Console.ReadKey();

        totalCharge = charge();
    }
    private static double charge (double daysOverdue, double booksChecked, 
      double totalCharge)
    {

        if (daysOverdue <= 7)
        {
          return totalCharge = booksChecked * daysOverdue * .10;
        }
        else
            {
            return (booksChecked * .70) + (booksChecked) * (daysOverdue - 7) 
         * (.20);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You declared it, but you didn't assign it a value.

Comment: `charge(...)` accepts three arguments, but you aren't passing any.

Comment: Not to mention both of those errors should already be explained in *plenty* of posts on this site (not to mention elsewhere)... Did you even research them at all? Google should be returning dozens of results for you.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Yes, I have googled them and none of the solutions have helped me so far.

Comment: @midnight_star10 - Really..? Those are some of the most straighforward errors you'll come across.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb more than likely they looked for the *exact* same thing they're doing, and don't have enough experience to understand that *similar* code can exhibit the same issue, or how to apply such fixes.  It's understandable for beginners.

Comment: @Amy - I get that to an extent. That second error will likely not turn up anything easy to find (quickly, anyway) in a google search. However, the first gives a solution in the first result. So in general, what you say is true, with the exception of the more simple/generically worded errors, such as the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems, which I'll review here.  My corrections are at the end of this answer.  I recommend putting your code and mine side by side and reviewing the differences carefully.

First, you cannot read the value out of a variable before you have assigned a value.  You must assign *something* to it first.

You need to call `charge(...)` *before* printing out the value of `totalCharge`.

Second, you don't need to pass the value of `totalCharge` to your `charge(...)` method: it *returns* the total charge!  So remove that parameter entirely.

Third, you need to *pass parameters* to the `charge` method.

Fourth, you had some formatting problems.  Please review my code to see how I've formatted my code differently.  If a line of code is continued onto the next line, use indentation to reflect this.  According to C# conventions, function names should be capitalized.

Lastly, this isn't necessarily a problem, but it doesn't look 'right': in two places, you are assigning `Convert.ToInt32(...)` to a `double`.  Why?  Those should be integers.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of books checked out.");
    double booksChecked = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of days they are overdue.");
    double daysOverdue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    // assign before printing out value
    // pass the two parameters into the function
    double totalCharge = Charge(daysOverdue, booksChecked);

    Console.WriteLine("Your total charge for {0} days overdue is {1:C}.", 
        daysOverdue, 
        totalCharge);

    Console.ReadKey();
}   

private static double Charge(double daysOverdue, double booksChecked)
{
    if (daysOverdue <= 7)
    {
        return booksChecked * daysOverdue * .10;
    }
    else
    {
        return (booksChecked * .70) + booksChecked * (daysOverdue - 7) * (.20);
    }
}
```